# Preventing warning 'GrEqualsBetweenInconvertibleTypes' when using '==' with a class implementing Comparable (Groovy)

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, comparable, intellij-inspections

Note that this question pertains to Groovy ('==' means equality rather than identity) and IntelliJ IDEA (but I don't believe this issue to be IDE-specific).

I have a class that implements comparable below:

```
class Money implements Comparable {
    BigDecimal value
    static final RoundingMode rounding = RoundingMode.HALF_UP

    Money(String stringValue) {
        if (stringValue) {
            this.value = roundToCent(new BigDecimal(formatString(stringValue)))
        } else {
            this.value = roundToCent(new BigDecimal(0))
        }
    }

    int compareTo(Money money) {
        return this.value <=> money.value
    }
    
    int compareTo(String string) {
        return this.value <=> roundToCent(new BigDecimal(string))
    }
    
    // I am aware equals methods aren't called here because compareTo is used on Comparables, 
    // however I figured it might give a better view of the issue.
    boolean equals(Money money) {
        def result = true
        if (money == null) {
            result = false
        } else if (this.value != money.value) {
            result = false
        }
        return result
    }
    boolean equals(other) {
        def result = true
        if (other == null) {
            result = false
        } else  {
            try {
                if (this.value != roundToCent(new BigDecimal(other))) {
                    result = false
                }
            } catch(ignored) {
                result = false
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    static String formatString(String string) {
        return string.replaceAll(/[^\d.]/, '')
    }

    static BigDecimal roundToCent(BigDecimal decimal) {
        return decimal.setScale(2, rounding)
    }

    static Money roundToCent(Money money) {
        money.value = roundToCent(money.value)
        return money
    }

    // Omitting methods not required for reproduction

}
```

So in this case, `new Money('10.00') == '10'` compiles and runs perfectly, but I still get the 'GrEqualsBetweenInconvertibleTypes' editor warning: `'==' between objects of inconvertible types 'Money' and 'String'`.

Direct question: **Is there a way to structure the class or method in Groovy to avoid this warning without having to turn it off altogether in the IDE settings?**

Unrelated: if you have any other suggestions for the design of the class, or if it just bothers you, feel free to comment on this post about it. I'm always open to improving something.

Comment: Your `equals(Object)` method is implemented in an unusual way that will make it not reflexive and will cause a `Money` instance to not be equal to itself per a call to that method.

Comment: Thanks for the input! In what case(s)? I might be missing something here
`def money = new Money('5') -> assert money == money` evaluates to true. If you mean the null case, null == null gets evaluated by Groovy separately. `Money money = null -> assert money == money` also evaluates to true.

Comment: When you do `money == money` the way your `Money` class is written, that won't involve `equals(Object)`, which is fine.  I am telling you that `equals(Object)` is going to misbehave when a `Money` instance is passed to it.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Is it possible for the Groovy method dispatch to pick the `equals(Object)` when a Money object is given? I have been directly calling `equals` with a Money object inside, and it's only giving me the `equals(Money)` version. In what cases will it pick `equals(Object)`? Might be a good idea to overload the numerical types anyway instead of using Object.

I also made a mistake earlier, as `equals` isn't used for the '==' operator for objects that implement Comparable. The `equals` still performs the same way, so thankfully it doesn't make too much of a difference lol

Comment: "Is it possible for the Groovy method dispatch to pick the equals(Object) when a Money object is given?" - Yes, but most of those ways you will have control over.  A separate concern is when you are interacting with anything that interacts with your `equals(Object)` method from Java.  For example, see https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/ba7e4a60c523edf9376e710cb9fc4755.  The collection is a Java class and the collection will not work well because your `.equals(Object)` deviates from standard expectations.